# Upload the file into the webapp folder

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

The user to upload the file with the txt extension to my system. I want this file to be accessible as `www.exp.com/text_file.txt`

But I could not do it. 
`Project/src/main/webapp/text_file.txt`  , If I drop the file under the webapp I can get it.
But how can I create txt file in webapp?

`new File(---);`  --> this code does not what I want. It creates under the eclipse folder.

```
Project
       ->pom.xml
       ->src
            ->main
                  ->java
                  ->resources
                  ->webapp
                          ->WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using servlets , this code should work (let's place file into webapp/resources)

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

      // Getting ServletContext from request
      ServletContext ctx= req.getServletContext();
      // Get the absolute path of the file
      String filename = ctx.getRealPath("resources/file.text");
      // getting mimeType of the file
      String mime = ctx.getMimeType(filename);
      // Error handling
      if (mime == null) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
      }

      // Setting MIME content type
      res.setContentType(mime);
      // Getting file object
      File file = new File(filename);
      // Setting content length header
      res.setContentLength((int)file.length());

       // FileInputStream to read from file
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
      // Obtain OutputStream from response object
      OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

      // Writing to the OutputStream
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int bytes = 0;
       //  we stop when in.read returns -1 and read untill it does not
       while ((bytes = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
         out.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
    // Clean up, closing resources
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks it works :), but I dont understand why this text file deleting when I change project and press CTRL + S

Comment: What do you mean it is deleting?

Comment: The created text file is deleted, when I change and save the servlet file